# Python vs C# Searching Collections

Tags: c#, python

Is there a short way to find if an object is in a collection in C# like with Pythons in operator, I reckon Linq brings you as close as you can get?

Comment: Are looking for *Linq* `Any(item => criterium)`?

Comment: [`List<T>.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be of use.

Comment: @shahkalpesh thanks, looks about as consise as can be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ***Linq*** `Any()`, e.g.

```
  // Whatever IEnumerable<T> collection
  int[] source = new int[] 
    {1, 2, 3, 4};

  // Put required criterium into Any()
  Boolean has = source.Any(item => item == 3);

  // You can put various criterium into Any(), not necessary ==:
  Boolean hasNegatives = source.Any(item => item < 0);
```